# How to sum two different functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have different functions which return values; So i created different function to sum both values.

```
function result(){
    var result = firstFunct() + secondFunct();
    alert(result);
    return result;
}
```

And it gives for me a result like joint of two strings: 1010 instead 20. What kind of operator do I need to use two sum both of them?

Comment: Make sure you return numbers from those functions, not strings, and don't return the `alert()` function, but the result.

Comment: Note also that it is confusing to have a variable (`result`) with the same name as the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most probably because your functions are returning string and not a numeric data type. You will need to cast the output of the functions

```
var result = Number(firstFunct()) + Number(secondFunct());
```

Note, casting to a number could also be done in a shorter way, using the `+` operator:

```
var result = (+firstFunct()) + (+secondFunct());
```

Comment: Thanks, it works... I been suspicious it is a string. Thanks again!

Comment: @MrVitaminasG - could you accept this answer?

Comment: I was waiting for countdown to vote. The system not giving to vote straight away

Answer (score 0):

To cast to a numeric you can also do:

`var num = 1 * numericstring;`

Comment: Well, `+numericString` is probably preferable.

Comment: This can be mistreated as concatenation.

Comment: Mistreated by whom, in what way? The unary plus has exactly one meaning, According to the documentation, "The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but **attempts to converts it into a number**, if it isn't already."

Comment: I mean syntactic constructs like `a + (+b)` and even `a++b` are ugly and prone for errors. These cannot be used in expressions as easily and clearly as `1*a + 1*b`.